# Intuit anywhere .net sample

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

For some reason I can't download any the .net/java samples provided at http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0010_Getting_Started/0030_Integrate_your_app/0030_Signing_Into_and_out_of_Intuit_From_Within_Your_App/Sign-in/Implement_SSO_and_OpenID_in_Your_App

Is code.intuit.com broken or something? I've tried several machines and browsers and the connection fails to connect to the site.

Otherwise, is there any good asp.net samples out there (preferably mvc). I found those
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code but there isn't as much details as I wished.

Comment: Yes, we are working on updating the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the official sample is now at https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code

There is a web forms sample but I got a message from Intuit saying the mvc samples should be available shortly.